# KSH Read input from file and write to CSV on SAME row

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have the following output and want the output to look:

FROM:

```
GigabitEthernet0/0 is up, line protocol is up
     1 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 1 overrun, 0 ignored
     275 output errors, 0 collisions, 3 interface resets
GigabitEthernet0/1 is up, line protocol is up
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     42 output errors, 0 collisions, 3 interface resets
```

TO: (in CSV format)

```
Interface, In Errors, Out Errors
GigabitEthernet0/0, 1, 275
GigabitEthernet0/1, 0, 42
```

When I put the above in a for loop I get staggered outputs as Im grepping on the turn of every loop

Heres my script

```
for line in $(cat $DATAFILE/$rname.intfs)
do
     intf=$(echo $line | grep "line protocol is " | awk '{print $1}')
     inerrs=$(echo $line | grep "input error" | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' | awk '{print $1}')
     outerrs=$(echo $line | grep "output error" | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' | awk '{print $1}')
     echo "$intf,$inerrs,$outerrs" >intf.csv
done
```

Any help is appreciated

thanks

Jay

Comment: Formatting doesnt show correct 
FROM:
GigabitEthernet0/0 is up, line protocol is up
     1 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 1 overrun, 0 ignored
     275 output errors, 0 collisions, 3 interface resets
GigabitEthernet0/1 is up, line protocol is up
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     42 output errors, 0 collisions, 3 interface resets

TO: (in CSV format)

Interface, In Errors, Out Errors
GigabitEthernet0/0, 1, 275
GigabitEthernet0/1, 0, 42

Comment: Use the curly braces:{}

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution (without shell loops and chains of pipelines):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ OFS=", "; print "Interface, In Errors, Out Errors" }
     /line protocol /{ ifc=$1 }
     /input errors/{ in_err=$1 }
     /output errors/{ print ifc, in_err, $1 }' "$DATAFILE/$rname.intfs"
```

The output:

```
Interface, In Errors, Out Errors
GigabitEthernet0/0, 1, 275
GigabitEthernet0/1, 0, 42
```